# Hibernate ManyToOne - OneToMany loop?

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-one, hibernate-annotations, hibernate-onetomany

i'm new to hibernate and i use annotations

These are my two tables:

[image]

This is my Table "Persona"

```
 @Entity
@Table(name = "persona")
public class Persona implements java.io.Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "codigo", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int codigo;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "codTipoIdent", nullable = false)
    private TipoIdentificacion tipoIdentificacion;

    ....
```

This is my second table "TipoIdentificacion"

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tipoIdentificacion")
public class TipoIdentificacion implements java.io.Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "codigo", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int codigo;

    @Column(name = "nombre", nullable = false)
    private String nombre;

    @Column(name = "siglas", nullable = false)
    private String siglas;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "tipoIdentificacion")    
    private Set<Persona> persona = new HashSet<Persona>(0);
```

the primary Key of "Persona" is "codigo" and for "TipoIdentificacion" is "codigo" wich is FK from persona (codTipoIdent)

everything looks fine, also i made a crud in my web app really well, but when i debug it for request a list of "TipoIdentificacion" it looks like

[image]

it make a loop, why?

Comment: You have two cars. The cars owner is you. And you have two cars. And the cars owner is you. And you have two cars... It's completely expected when you have a *bidirectional* association.

Comment: yes i know more of that now, thanks =) I appreciate it.